# Regression factor scores

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, data-transformation

I am new to statistics and I have an issue here but I am not sure how to put it into words correctly. I did a factor analysis which resulted to three factors and then I used their factor scores to create three linear models for another DV. The problem is that I cannot interpret the factor scores in terms of their estimated effect. I use regression factor scores which are standard scores with a Mean = 0 and Variance = squared multiple correlation  between items and factor.

Is there any way to rescale the factor scores to correspond to the metric of the latent variable (same mean, sd, and range) and be more meaningful?

````
m1 <- lm(Totalpoints ~ FAC1, samp)
m2 <- lm(Totalpoints ~ FAC2, samp)
m3 <- lm(Totalpoints ~ FAC3, samp)```
````

Comment: Factor variances of orthogonal factors equal sums of squares of their loadings. So, to take f. scores to have those variances, standardize f. scores of the given factor (to have variance exactly 1) and then multiply by the sq. root(variance) of that factor.